# date picker is covered by applet when use p:calendar and applet

Tags: java, primefaces, applet

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p:calendar showOn="button"  value="*" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<applet></applet>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

when I used primefaces and applet I occured a problem that when I click the date picker button, the popup picker is covered by applet.

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of css

just warp your `applet` with a `div`

for example

```
<div id="applet_wrapper">
     <applet></applet>
</div>
```

And play with its css display or position

for example (in your css file...):

```
#applet_wrapper{
    display :block; //or inline-block
}
```

Comment: try playing with its style (div style) do it directly from chrome/firefox dev tools...

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use SimpleDateFormat by which you can be covered you date difference in java applet.

> Date d1 = null;
>           Date d2 = null;

```
    d1 = format.parse(logindate1);
    d2 = format.parse(logoutdate);

    //in milliseconds
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
    System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
    System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
    System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");
```

I got same problem but after some search i found [date picker in applet](http://techdilute.com/date-difference-in-java/). I hope it will help you